# Write output of str() to file connection using cat

Tags: r, file-io

I know that I can use `sink()` to redirect output from console.  For example, I can write the column descriptions of the `iris` dataset:

```
data(iris)
sink('iris.txt')
writeLines('Description of Iris Dataset:')
cat(str(iris))
sink()
```

makes a file `iris.txt` with the **desired output**:

```
Description of Iris Dataset:
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Can I do the same thing using `cat()`?  I tried:

```
con <- file('iris.txt','w')
writeLines('Description of Iris Dataset:',con)
cat(str(iris),file=con,append=TRUE)
close(con)
```

But only the first line is written to file. The `str()` silently fails to write.

Under `?cat` > Details we find:

> Currently only atomic vectors and names are handled, together with
>   NULL and other zero-length objects (which produce no output).
>   Character strings are output ‘as is’ (unlike print.default which
>   escapes non-printable characters and backslash — use encodeString if
>   you want to output encoded strings using cat). Other types of R object
>   should be converted (e.g., by as.character or format) before being
>   passed to cat. That includes factors, which are output as integer
>   vectors.

After reading this I tried wrapping `str(iris)` with `as.character()` (no difference) and `format()` (adds NULL on second line).

This may seem nitpicky, but the reason I would like to avoid `sink()` is because I would like to write some things to console in between writes to file, and opening and closing the sink makes an extra step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `capture.output()` to turn the result of the `str()` into a simple character vector.

Try:

```
cat(capture.output(str(iris)), file=con, append=TRUE, sep="\n")
```

Comment: Ah, ok.  `as.character()` wasn't working because (from `?str` > Value) "str does not return anything, for efficiency reasons. The obvious side effect is output to the terminal."

Comment: `cat` is a quintessential operate-via side-effects function. It makes it useful as a debugging tool.